# GSM Shield not reading full SMS Message body

Tags: arduino, sms, gsm, at-command, arduino-ide

I am using Arduino Uno R3 with SIM900A  (http://www.rhydolabz.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=1080) .

The problem that I am facing now is that I am not able to read SMS body Stored on the sim card. Everytime I query it gives a different result, for example:

```
AT+CMGR=27
+CMGR: "REC READ","+91xxxxxxxxxx","","13/10/31,01:22:59+22",145,36,0,0,"+9198319"5
,i no negepornu ts,tsnwYfm


AT+CMGR=27
+CMGR: "REC READ","+91xxxxxxxxxx","","13/10/31,01:22:59+22",145,36,0,0,"+9198319,,
,s n aneeesn  s ts,t egoem


AT+CMGR=27
+CMGR: "REC READ","+91xxxxxxxxxx","","13/10/31,01:22:59+22",145,36,0,0,"+919831011
  ggb gs?rsgt st s   egoee
```

This was after I changed :

```
AT+CSMP=49
OK
```

Before that when 
Code:

```
AT+CSMP=17
```

the output was :

```
AT+CMGR=27
+CMGR: "REC READ","+91xxxxxxxxxx","","13/10/31,01:22:59+22"
So, this is going  agseesnt st s,  egoee
```

in which "So, this is going  " was only a small part of very long test message. I've searched it everywhere but cannot find why this is happening. I also tried to search for any AT Commands to set the SMS Text mode parameters to show me a complete message but nothing  is working. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see below reasons:

1. You are communicating with SIM900 too fast. Try reduce Arduino-SIM900 baudrate.
2. You are communicating with Arduino too fast. Try reduce Arduino-PC baudrate.
3. Check cable connections.
4. Change your terminal application (Arduino-PC). Arduino IDE internal terminal seems to be not reliable sometimes.

Comment: I forgot to update this question here. You're right, decreasing the baud rate to 4800 from 9600 solved the problem. I cannot understabd why that happened though. The Gsm shield is mentioned to work fine with baud rates of 9600 and higher. Do you have any ideas on this?

Comment: Probably you could try hardware serial on 9600 bps. But in this case you will loose USB connection. Software serial requires small loops/delays to communicate stable.